# jcenter Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: android, jcenter

15:55:42: Executing external task 'bintrayUpload'...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:kf5sdklibrary:bintrayUpload FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':kf5sdklibrary:bintrayUpload'.

  > java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 40.78 secs
15:56:23: External task execution finished 'bintrayUpload'.

the exception of upload with DNS.

I have tried many times, but it doesn't work.Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: I had a same problem and I thought maybe because the `bintray.com` can't be visited for now.

Answer (score 0):

it is your network enviroment problem,in my company,i meet the same problem "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error",but when i go home,i use "gradlew bintrayUpload" build successful